# Call of method in inheritance

Tags: java

I had a problems about the type of the objects and which method they can call.

I was just testing the usage of inheritance and I define two classes: superclass Person and subclass Student. The code is as below.

```
public class Person{

  private String name;
  private int birthday;

  public Person(){

  }

  public Person(String name, int birthday){
    this.name=name;
    this.birthday=birthday;
  }

  public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
  }

  public void setBirth(int birthday){
    this.birthday=birthday;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  public int getBirth(){
    return birthday;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return "Name: "+name+"\n"+"Birthday: "+birthday;
  }

  public void print(Person a){
    System.out.println(toString());
  }
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student extends Person{
  private String major;

  public Student(){}

  public Student(String major,String name,int birthday){
    super(name,birthday);
    this.major = major;

  }

  public void setMajor(String major){
    this.major=major;
  }

  public String getMajor(){
    return major;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "Name: "+getName()+" BOD: "+getBirth()+" Major: "+getMajor();
  }

  public void print(){
    System.out.println(toString());
  }

}
```

Tester.

```
public class persontest{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    //Part 1

    Person p2 = new Person("p2 Ryan", 19920604);
    p2.print(p2);

//Test 1 p2-->Student
    p2=new Student();// what does it mean??
    p2.print(p2); //which 'toString' should be called??


//1.If p2 is now a Student Why can't invoke Student's print()? (Uncomment 'p2.print()')

//        p2.print();

//2. If p2 isn't a Studnet, why is it able to call Student's toString()? (Uncomment toString in Student)

  }
}
```

I declare 'toString()' method and 'print()' method in both Person and Student class.

As the method 'print()' has parameter in Person class while that doesn't have parameter in Student class, I think this method is overloaded instead of being overridden.

'toString' method has been overridden in Student class.

In Part 1, I create an object p2 with initialisation of name and birthday and the output is satisfied (Name: p2 Ryan  Birthday: 19920604).
)

Then I tried 'p2=new Student()', so what does this mean? Changing the type of p2 from Person to Student?

Then I did 'p2.print(p2)' which I think called the method ' print()' in Person class, but which 'toString' has been called and used as the parameter? The printout is (Name: null BOD: 0 Major: null), which I thought indicated that the Student's 'toString' method has been called and processed. And it might prove that p2 now is a type of Person?

However, when I tried to get p2 call 'print()' in Student method, error came up as 'The method print(Person) in the type Person is not applicable for the arguments ()', which seems to say that p2 is still a Person so that it cannot call the method 'print()' defined in Student class.

So I got confused that what type is p2?

Comment: Your `Person.print()` method does not make much sense since the method would already have internal access to the object whose fields you want to print.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply, but I don't quite understand you explanation, would you mind rephrasing it?

Comment: **What a mess!** You create a person without a name? Even if in the first seconds after birth the parents may not decided what name the child may have, a student always have a name! For a matriculation you need at least a sign and XXX is presumably not very usually for a student.

Comment: Use this: `public void print() { System.out.println(this.toString()); }`

Comment: looks like asking for someone to do your homework?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, hi Meisch, it's not about my homework, just a small testing of how it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Weak and strong types: A representation:

Each variable that is not a primitive can be seen to have a weak type and a strong type. The weak type is used for overload resolution and for the compiler to see what interface an object has. But the strong type is used when actually calling a method on an object. Note: **the strong type is always the same as, or a direct or indirect subtype of the weak type**. Let's have a look:

```
A obj = new A();
```

Both the weak and strong type is `A`.

```
A obj = new B();
```

The weak type is `A` but the strong type is `B`.

The compiler uses the weak type to check which interface (the collection of methods) an object has. So we can only call methods from `A` on `obj` and not from `B`. So if the classes look like this:

```
class A { }

class B extends A {
    public void bMehtod(){
        ...
    }
}
```

We cannot call `bMethod` on `obj`, because `bMethod` is not part of `A`'s interface.

For the sake of overriding, The strong type is used when *actually* calling a method. It's like the JVM starts at the strong type and moves up the inheritance chain until it finds an occurrence of the method that was called. So if our classes look like this:

```
class A {
     public String toString() {
        return "A";
     }
}

class B extends A {
    public String toString() {
         return "B";
    }
}
```

And we create an object and call `toString`:

```
A obj = new B();
System.out.println(obj); // this will call 'obj.toString()'
```

The JVM will start at the strong type (`B`) and look for a `toString` method. If it can't find any, it will move up the inheritance chain. But, `B` overrides `toString` so `B`'s `toString` will get called. This becomes more apparent when a third class is added:

```
class C extends B { }
```

If we now create an object and call `toString`:

```
A obj = new C();
System.out.println(obj);
```

The JVM will start at `C` looking for a `toString` method, it wont find any and move up, to `B`, where it finds a `toString` method. So `B`'s `toString` method will get called.

#### How does this relate to your problem:

Just like other variables, `this` has a weak and strong type. The weak type is the class in which the `this` keyword is written. The strong type is the actual type with which an object was created.

In your `print` method:

```
public void print(Person a){
    System.out.println(toString());
}
```

The `toString()` is implicitly translated to `this.toString()`. The weak type of `this` is `Person`, so it's okay to call `toString` on it, it's a part of `Person`'s interface. But the strong type is what you actually used to create the object:

```
p2 = new Student();
```

The strong type of `this` is `Student`, so the JVM will start at `Student` when looking for a `toString` method, and it finds it in `Student`. So `Student`'s `toString` method is called.

---

Like I said this is just a representation, the *actual* way it is implemented could vary per JVM. But it will still behave the same.

Also, see [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/NwkRWK)

Comment: Thank you very much Jorn, you are really nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class persontest{
public static void main(String[] args){

//Part 1

Person p2 = new Person("p2 Ryan", 19920604);
p2.print(p2);
// Here super class variable p2 is holding super class object. Hence print() method of Person class will be called which is indirectly calling toString() of Person class only

//Test 1 p2-->Student
p2=new Student();// It means Super class variable P2 is now holding subclass Student object.
//It means now whenever we try to call a method, it will first check whether it is available in subclass or not
// if available it will be called, if not available, it will check in superclass for same method
p2.print(p2); //which 'toString' should be called??
// Now as you called print(p2)-> JVM will check whether a print method with one parameter is available in Student class or not?
// As per your code it is not available, then it will check if Print method with one parameter is available in super class. It is available
// Hence super class print method will be called. As there it is calling toString() which is available in that class only 
//hence Person class toString will be called

//1.If p2 is now a Student Why can't invoke Student's print()? (Uncomment 'p2.print()')
```

//        p2.print();

//2. If p2 isn't a Studnet, why is it able to call Student's toString()? (Uncomment toString in Student)

}
}

Answer (score 0):

With `Person p2 = new Student()` you have  declared a new variable of type Person but assigned a student object to it. 
The variable type is still person so you can not directly call methods from student on it. 
To do so you have to cast it to student first

```
((student) p2).print()
```

This will invoke the `print()` method from student class.

However if you are overwriting a method you always invoke the method from your object because the complier checks to run time of which type your  object is and calls the method on this object. This is called dynamic binding.

The only way to access the overwritten method from person in a student object is to invoke the method with `super` so:

```
super.toString();
```

But that can only be done inside the student class.

Comment: Hi Dimi, thank you for your reply, I think it makes some sense to me, However, since you said p2 is still a Person's variable, then why does it print the content of Student's toString when p2 calls the 'print(p2)', instead of the content of Person's toString?

Comment: with p2 = new Student() you have assigned a new object to p2, so the values for name and birth are null of course, because you've never set them

Comment: do p2.setName(), p2.setBirth()and  p2.setMajor() before the print

Comment: Yes, I didn't set them as I just wanted to test of which class the method will be called by p2 after it is assigned to a 'new Student()'.

Comment: So the weird is after being assigned 'new Student()', p2 can invoke print(Person p) defined in Person but call Student's 'toString' in the statement of this method(because the output is the content of Student's 'toString', rather than Person's . But it should not be able to call 'toString' of Student because p2 is still a 'Person', isn't it?

Comment: no as I tried to explain if you are calling a method on person, the JVM will check to run time if the method is overwritten in your object class (student), if so it will execute the method from student.

Comment: The point of why you can't call e.g print() directly is because the JVM doesn't know to compile time if the object stored in p2 is a student, so you can only access the methods from person if you don't cast and explicit tell the compiler that this is an student

Comment: Ok, thanks I understand this part. As you said, JVM doesn't know p2 has became a Student if I don't explicitly tell it Then why is the return value of Student's toString printed out when p2 is calling Person's print()method, which is 'public void print(Person p){ System.out.println(toString());}. ?

Comment: Because toString() is defined in Person it is ensured that the method exits no matter what object you assign to Person, so p2.toString() wont give you an error.  Now comes the part where overwriting matters: If you call p2.toString() the JVM checks of which type your object is and if the method is overwritten there it will invoke this instead the one from person. This is possible because both methods have the same signature and it can be checked in run time. This is exactly what overwriting is.

Comment: Thank you Dimi, now I got a better understanding on it!